# Regex: match after capture group 1 match, using it's result

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm having trouble understanding what I did wrong in the regex below:

`/^([^#]+)#(\1.*?(?=\||$))/gi`

It correctly matches `foo#foo,xyz,asd123|bar,asd123,xyz`, with the desired result being `foo,xyz,asd123`.

But it does not match `bar#foo,xyz,asd123|bar,asd123,xyz`. Expected output would be `bar,asd123,xyz`.

Basically, I need to use the result of the capture group 1 to search further in the string after the # character. However, it's only working for the match immediately after # and nothing else. I feel like I'm missing a very basic thing here.

[regexr.com/6ussf](https://regexr.com/6ussf)

Comment: Did you mean `^([^#]+)#.*(\1.*?(?=\||$))`? Because `#(\1…` will only match the first group directly after the # character. If text is allowed after the #, but before the captured value, you need to express that (e.g. with `.*`: match anything) <https://regexr.com/6ust4>

Comment: Looks like `^([^#]+)#.*?(\1[^|]*)` will be enough, unless you want to avoid matching in case like `foo#foobar,xyz,asd123|bar,asd123,xyz`

Comment: Will `foo` and `bar` contain only word characters? Do you need to match cases like `foo#foobar,xyz,asd123|bar,asd123,xyz`

Comment: Could you please clarify if anything helped here, or add more details to the question.

Comment: Thanks knittl and Wictor! Both of the answers helped. A mix of both ``^([^#]+)#.*?(\1.*?(?=\||$))`` is exactly what I needed to achieve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^([^#]+)#.*?(\1.*?)(?=\||$)
```

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `([^#]+)` - Group 1 (`\1`): one or more chars other than `#`
- `#` - a `#` char
- `.*?` - zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(\1.*?)` - Group 2: same value as captured into Group 1 and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=\||$)` - a positive lookahead that requires `|` or end of string immediately to the right of the current location.